# how to install BND environment to use bnd in commandline?

Tags: java, command-line, osgi

I need to use bnd in a command line environment to develop OSGI project. 
I searched the following site: http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Download  But there are no instructions for how to install bnd in a command line environment.

Can anybody can give me some information? I need detailed instructions.

My purpose is to use `bnd` in windows XP as follows:

```
bnd aQute.tutorial.chat.bnd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bnd command is a shell script that executes the following command:

```
java -jar biz.aQute.bnd.jar
```

You will have to make that script yourself.

(as mentioned on http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Download)

Answer (score 1):

Download bnd and start it with Java. You should download bnd from [jpm](http://jpm4j.org/#!/p/osgi/biz.aQute.bnd) (select the latest master or staging version, and download from that revision page) or from [Cloudbees](https://bndtools.ci.cloudbees.com/job/bnd.master/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/dist/bundles/biz.aQute.bnd/).

Once you've downloaded, you should have a file ***biz.aQute.bnd-#.#.#.jar***. You can run this file from the command line line:

```
C:/> java -jar biz.aQute.bnd-#.#.#.jar version
2.3.0.20131118-174557
```

You could place this in a .bat file like:

```
@java -jar biz.aQute.bnd-#.#.#.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %4 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Answer (score 0):

- [Download from the maven repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/biz/aQute/bnd/bnd/2.4.0/bnd-2.4.0.jar)
- Using [jpm4j.org](http://www.jpm4j.org) then you can easily install bnd on the command line with sudo jpm install -f bnd